# SQL connecting table and comparing value in same column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

Hello I have these two tables:

```
Team:
team_id
team_name
division
```

and

```
Match:
match_id
match_date
...
Team_team_id
Team_team_id1
```

Example of the Team data:

```
(1, Anaheim, P)
(2, Arizona, P)
(3, Boston, S)
(4, Buffalo, M)
(5, Detroit, M)
```

and Match:

```
(1, date, 1, 2)
(2, date, 2, 3)
(3, date, 5, 3)
```

and result should be only Anaheim(played against Arizona in same division)

I want to list only team's names, which played matches only against teams in the same division. How could I do that in SQL and relational algebra? Division is only character value. Thank you for any help...

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. And you should work a litle more in the schema/data you have now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.team_name AS team_name1,
       t2.team_name AS team_name2
FROM   team t1
       INNER JOIN match m
       ON ( t1.team_id = m.team_team_id )
       INNER JOIN team t2
       ON ( t2.team_id = m.team_team_id1 )
WHERE  t1.division = t2.division
```

Comment: Interesting that this is the correct answer - the original question asked for single team names (Anaheim was the only correct answer) but this query, the accepted "correct answer", returns **pairs** of teams. Also, the original question disqualifies a team (Arizona) if it played against teams in other divisions, even if they also played against a team in their division. This Answer doesn't do that. Yet the OP is happy. Go figure.

Comment: @mathguy Firstly, this answer was posted before the OP updated the post with sample data - please check the timestamps. Secondly, for the sample data the query will output `only Anaheim(played against Arizona in same division)` - exactly what the OP asked for that Anaheim played Arizona. Now if you want to play semantics with the English language about whether or not this was what the question that was asked then feel free to post your **own** answer or you could just accept the OPs comment immediately prior to yours.

Comment: @MT0 - My comment was really meant for the OP, not so much for you. I was going to offer a solution, but I can't take the OP seriously after accepting your answer, he clearly is confused. With that said, I still don't see how your query returns a single team name and not a pair of names, even disregarding everything else.